# JPA limits `queryResultList` even though `setMaxResults` is not definied

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, named-query

I have written the following code snippet to fetch records of certain zip files from `zips` table using `hibernate` as the JPA provider.

```
    public List<ZipEntity> getZipEntityFromZipName(String zipName, String version, String createdBy,
                                                      String type) throws FileException {

        int numAttempts = 0;
        do {
            numAttempts++;
            EntityManager entityManager = getNewEntityManager();
            try {
                TypedQuery<ZipEntity> query = entityManager
                        .createNamedQuery(Constants.Database.Queries.GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME, ZipEntity.class)
                        .setParameter("zipName", zipName)
                        .setParameter("version", version)
                        .setParameter("createdBy", createdBy)
                        .setParameter("type", type);
                return query.getResultList();
            } catch (PersistenceException e) {
                validatePersistenceException(e);
            } finally {
                closeEntityManager(entityManager);
            }
        } while (numAttempts <= maxRetries);
        throw new FileException("Database connection failed.");
```

Here are the relevant entity classes

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = Constants.Database.Queries.GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME,
                query = Constants.Database.Queries.GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME_QUERY,
                resultClass = ZipEntity.class
        )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "zips")
public class ZipEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ZipKey ZipKey;

    public ZipEntity() {

    }

    public ZipEntity(String zipName, String version, String createdBy, String file, String type,
                      String extension) {

        this.ZipKey = new ZipKey(zipName, version, createdBy, file, type, extension);
    }
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ZipKey implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "zip_name")
    private String zipName;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private String version;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "filepath")
    private String file;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "extension")
    private String extension;

 // Getter, setters and Constructor
}
```

And the query in Constant class is as follows,

```
public static final String GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME = "getFile";
public static final String GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM zips WHERE zip_name = " +
                    ":zipName AND version = :version AND created_by = :createdBy AND type = :type";
```

Event though `setMaxResults()` is not defined for the above query the results obtained from the above code snippet are limited to 25 record, although the  same query executed at DB results in 35 records. What I am doing wrong in here ?

Comment: Can you enable H2 Console and share the generated query ?. i assume that like "limit ?" at end of your query.

Comment: getResultList() will fetch all the records and it will not limit the number of records to be selected. The problem may be in your where condition like it may be ignored null or empty values

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara no, I checked the logs no `limit ?` at the end

Comment: to segregate the problem, i would suggest you to check the ran query in db. in oracle , you can get it as  "select * from v$sql" .For this ,you should be having a dedicated test db , which is not running concurrent queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug your solution and check values of "zipName","version","createdBy" and also "type" parameters to verify that they are the expected values by you. This query has for conditions combined by AND logic which affects to your results.  To get 35 records, your parameters should make your conditions true for all 35 records.

You can limit the records as below in NamedNativeQuery which provides you 35 records at a time.

```
 @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = Constants.Database.Queries.GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME,
                query = Constants.Database.Queries.GET_FROM_ZIP_NAME_QUERY,
                fetchSize = 35,
                resultClass = ZipEntity.class
        )
```